# How to implement clock() of c++ in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to implement clock method in c# and get difference time of two clock as describe in below code. I use timers ,stopwatch and DateTime in c# but i didn't get correct time as i get in c++. 
C++ code is describe below :

```
clock_t start_time, diff_time;
start_time = clock();
int i = 0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
.....
}
diff_time = clock();
diff_time -= start_time;
```

C# code is :

```
  var start_time = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
                            i++;
                        var diff_time = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                        var diff_times = (start_time.ElapsedTicks - diff_time.ElapsedTicks);
```

Comment: If you didn't get the correct result, show the code you wrote, what the results were and what they were supposed to be

Comment: Definitely use `StopWatch` for timing code. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime/

Comment: stopwatch does what you expect it to, the units are different - your clock() code ignores CLOCKS_PER_SEC .

Comment: Because of the differences in how the code executes in C++ ad C# you will most likely NOT get the same time. I agree with @juharr Stopwatch is the way to go.

Comment: @Sami  i implement below code :   var start_time =Stopwatch.StartNew();

         for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
                        i++;
                    var diff_time = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    var diff_times = (start_time.ElapsedTicks - diff_time.ElapsedTicks);  Output with c++ code is 4877 but output with c# code is 14222044.

Comment: your C# code is measuring the different time between 2 stopwatches that are still running. Just use 1 stopwatch, start at some point and stop at some point, then take a look at the elapsed time. Tick is arbritrary time unit, it might be better to show in (mili)seconds instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think StopWatch should be used to measure code performance and other similar comparisons. If is the case, ok.
Or else, maybe you should consider DateTime.Now

The C function clock() returns a clock_t value that is the number of clock ticks elapsed since the program started. The number of seconds used by the CPU is obtained dividing this result by CLOCKS_PER_SEC.

For DateTime, check:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8
-> Some parts below:

The DateTime value type represents dates and times measured in 100-nanosecond units called ticks. Example: in the gregorian calendar a ticks value of 31241376000000000L represents the date Friday, January 01, 0100 12:00:00 midnight.

...
If you are working with a ticks value that you want to convert to some other time interval, such as minutes or seconds, you should use the TimeSpan.TicksPerDay, TimeSpan.TicksPerHour, TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute, TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond, or TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond constant to perform the conversion. For example, to add the number of seconds represented by a specified number of ticks to the Second component of a DateTime value, you can use the expression 
dateValue.Second + nTicks/Timespan.TicksPerSecond.
...

Comment: Obs. Stopwatch(C#) and clock(C++) are fit to different purposes. Your C++ code is NOT obtaining the most precise time evaluation as you probably desire. I would bet the "wrong" code is the C++ one in order to do what you want.

Comment: In english the link is - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation of the Clock() function in C#

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long CLOCKS_PER_SEC = 10000000;
        long lngElapsedTime_t = Clock();
        long lngElapsedTime;
        int i, j, k, m;
        for (i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
        {
            j = i / 50;
            k = j * 50;
            m = i - k;
            if (m == 1) { Console.WriteLine(i); }
        }
        lngElapsedTime = (Clock() - lngElapsedTime_t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        Console.WriteLine("<<{0}>> The time in Ticks", lngElapsedTime_t);
        Console.WriteLine("<<{0}>> The elapsed time in seconds", lngElapsedTime);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static long Clock()
    {
        long clock_t = (long)DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        return clock_t;
    }
```